# What is the meaning of Shivaaya?

Tags: shiva, name

We know Shiva is the Lord. But it is not clear what is meant by Shivaaya ?

My question is : What is the meaning of Shivaaya ?

Comment: You mean சிவாய இல்லை சிவய ?

Comment: Shivaya means to Shiva.. Om namah shivaya.. means prostration to Shiva.. for female deities like Durga it will Om durgayai namaha.. so here yai instead of ya.

Comment: @Rickross please add that as an answer.

Comment: @DheerajVerma But I need to find some references too.

Comment: @DheerajVerma You are asking the meaning of Shivaya from Panchakshari mantra "Namah Shivaya". Aren't you? Are you asking something else?

Comment: User Sarvabhouma has changed the meaning of this post AFTER this question was answered. This is not allowed after the question was answered. And I think it is now different to the original post because Shivay and Shivaya are different words. See my answer to this question too.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, we have not only mantras here! E.g. we have indian movie **[Shivaay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivaay)** from 2016. If someone speak Shivay you do not need to correct him because in your opinion we have the mantra with Shivaya form.

Comment: @Bharata Well, we talk about manras only. Movies are not our cup of tea. The OP also asked about Shivaya from mantra andthat is clear from accepted answer. We have a policy about using Sankrit words instead of Hindi etc., that is not changing meaning of the question. You should clarify what Op means before posting answer.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, not! Hinduism is not only mantras! Hinduism is the whole Vedic culture. Accepted answer could be completly different from the question. E.g. even if the answer would be about Ganesh. The OP can freely choose the answer - this is in the rules of SE/SO. And **[this is not a policy](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/233)** like moderator Keshav Srinivasan♦ wrote in his answer. Please read it attentively before you write here about some policyes.

Comment: ... Moderator Keshav Srinivasan♦ wrote: Shiva vs Siva vs Siva with a dot under the s. Those are all valid transliterations of the Sanskrit word in different Devanagari transliteration systems like IAST and ITRANS. You should clarify what Op means before changing of answer meaning.

Comment: @Bharata is correct.  Si va ya, Si vaa ya are different.  SI VA. All these different sound vibrations give an aspirant different kinds of results. On whole here with respect to Siva, its more of transcendental vibrations than which is manifest to see by us.

Comment: * In my last comment I should write:  before changing of **question** meaning. It was the typo.

Comment: @DheerajVerma your original question was fully OK. I suggested a rollback to your original question. Please accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

शिवाय (Śivāya) is **4th Vibhakti** of शिव (Shiva). 4th Vibhakti means **to/for whom**.

So the meaning of Śivāya would be **to/for Shiva**.

Example: ॐ नमः शिवाय (Om Namah Shivaya): Om salutations to Lord Shiva!

---

Below are the basic details on 8 Vibhaktis:

1. 1st: Subject
2. 2nd: Object
3. 3rd: by/with/through whom
4. 4th: to/for whom
5. 5th: from whom
6. 6th: shows possession (E.g. Ram's or of Ram)
7. 7th: in/on whom
8. 8th: when addressing

The below lines of [Ram Raksha Stotra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Raksha_Stotra) have all the Vibhaktis in order:

> **रामो** राजमणिः सदा विजयते **रामं** रमेशं भजे।
>
> **रामेण** अभिहता निशाचरचमू **रामाय** तस्मै नमः।
>
> **रामात्** नास्ति परायणं परतरं **रामस्य** दासोस्म्यहम्।
>
> **रामे** चित्तलयः सदा भवतु मे **भो राम!** मामुद्धर।।३७॥
>
> I worship **Rama** whose jewel (among kings) who always wins and **who is
>   lord of Lakshmi** (goddess of wealth)। **Through whom** the hordes of demons
>   who move at night have been destroyed, I salut that Rama [my salutations **to** that **Rama**]।
>
> There is no place of surrender **greater than Rama**, (and thus) I am
>   servant **of Rama**।
>
> My mind is totally absorbed **in Rama**. **O Rama**, please lift me up (from
>   lower to higher self)॥37॥

Answer (score 4):

**Shivay and Shivaya**

We have a lot of meanings from Shiva (sanskrit शिव, IAST: Śiva) in the Vedas, but I will write about the etymology.

The teacher Bal Gangadhar Tilak in 1903 wrote the book **["The Arctic Home in the Vedas"](http://vedic-nation.com/media/research_activities/9_arctic_home_in_the_vedas.pdf)** (*the link to full english book in PDF*). In it, he argued that the Vedas could only have been composed in the Arctics, and the Aryans (slavic folks) brought them south after the onset of the last ice age.

**[Šiwa, Živa, also Živena, Żiwia, Siva, Sieba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%BDiva_(mythology))**, is the slavic goddess of life and fertility. She is worshiped throughout what is now Poland, the Czech Republic, Slovakia, and Germany (and especially the Elbe (Labe) river valley), before Christianity expanded into the area. Her name means "living, being, existing".

A large and dark main-belt **[asteroid "140 Siwa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/140_Siwa)** (ˈʃiːwə) was discovered 1874 and named after Šiwa, the Slavic god.

In India the name Shiva is spoken from a lot of people like Siwa too.

When we would like to translate the word Zhiva (Šiwa / Živa) from slavic language into english then we have this meanings:

- living; someone who lives;
- source of life.

I think Shivay and Shivaya are the forms of russian words Zhivoy (rus. Живой) and Zhivaya (rus. Живая). We can understand the meaning only if we go to russian language. Zhivoy (rus. Живой) is in english "one men, who lives". And Zhivaya (rus. Живая) is in english "one woman, who lives".

This is my knowlege. And I hope it can help someone.

*Hare Hare Mahadev! Ohm Namah Shivaya!*

> **Concept of god Ardhanaareeswara** - half men and half woman of god Shiva.
>
> The half-man half-woman **[Ardhanareeswar](https://www.thehinduportal.com/2015/11/concept-of-ardhanaareeswara-half-women.html)** represents the union of Shiva
>   and Shakti, the basic tenets of creation, the unchanging Consciousness
>   and Drive that gives motility.
>
> [image: Shiva as half-man half-woman Ardhanareeswar]

Comment: The first source question was **["What is the meaning of _Shivay_?"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/28745/1)**. And later it was corrected from moderator.

Answer (score 3):

சிவாய என்ற அச்சரம் சிவம் இருக்கும் அச்சரம் 
உபாயம் என்று நம்புவோருக்கு உண்மையான அச்சரம் - சித்தர் சிவவாக்கியர் பாடல்

This is Siddhar Sivavakkiyar song about true nature of soul = which is Shiva.

"The soul is running it's life in the body in the sound vibration of Si va ya

And this vibration works only for truly surrendered souls to the supreme"

Si va ya here refers to the sound in which your soul is living in the body. Also out of five elements of nature, the fire, air, and space energy's Sound vibration are - SI VA YA (not Shivay). The more you utter the mantra SI VA YA - it directly connects you to spiritual realm of vibrations.

That's why even avvaiyar also said "Those who think of SI VA YA without any deviation, for them no harm is done"

Comment: This is an English Language site and answers should be in English only. Not many users can understand Tamil. Transliterate Tamil into English script.

Comment: I have given explanation in English on the song

Comment: I asked for transliteration. Transliteration means writing other language into understandable script. Write it in English script. We can't read Tamil or understand it. Only English is allowed here. Use @username to reply otherwise I won't be notified again.